# Sort numerically a list of data frames

Tags: r

I'm trying to sort a list of data frames that looks like this:

> ```
>    List of 16
>    $ 0 :'data.frame':.........
>    ..$ rownames(Meta)
>    $ 1 :'data.frame':.........
>      ..$ rownames(Meta)
>    $ 11 :'data.frame':.........
>      ..$ rownames(Meta)
>    $ 12 :'data.frame':.........
>      ..$ rownames(Meta)
>      .........
> ```

I tried the following but without success:

> ```
>  v = rep(0:15, times = 1)
>  out[order(v)]
> ```

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is this all the output you received?  Or is there more you can share?

Comment: Maybe  `out[order(as.numeric(names(out)))]`.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: `out[stringr::str_order(names(out), numeric = TRUE)]`?